# Docusaurus Build and Deployment with GitHub Actions

Tags: deployment, github-actions, github-pages, docusaurus

I made a GitHub action in order to build and deploy my docusaurus site on a GitHub page following the docusaurus documentation.

When I make a modification in one of my project file, the GitHub action works well, the pipeline works, the branch master has been updated and the gh-pages branch too, but when I refresh my GitHub page, the modification is not displayed.

Does someone know what could be the issue? I saw that the issue could come from the use of `GITHUB_TOKEN`?

Comment: Same has been happening with me but now very close to the solution, would post soon.